# Mongojs print and console.log not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongojs

I am running the following command and I want to see the output in my out.log file but it is not printing anything.

```
   /tmp/mongodb/bin/mongo mydatabase_name /tmp/mongodb/scripts/test.js >> out.log
```

These are the contents in my test.js

```
db.system.js.save (
{   _id:"run_job",
    value: function() {

    console.log("in function");
    print("in function>>");
    db.myUser.find().forEach(
    function(eachuser){
        console.log("eachuser id" + eachuser._id);
        var lower_id = eachuser._id.toLowerCase();
        console.log("Lowercase id" + lower_id);
    });     
    }
}
 );
```

It give error : invoke failed: JS error : console is not defined. So it removed the console.log. But it still does not print using the print function.
Thanks.

Comment: `Print` & `printjson` both go to the mongod log file instead of the console. There's no `console` object in the MongoDB console. :)

Comment: Also, make sure that you don't have a `logpath` configured for mongod. If it's not set, all output from print (and other logging) should go to `/dev/stdout`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . So there is no other way I can get output in the out.log file?

Comment: What's wrong with `print` and `printjson`? There's no `console` object defined.

Comment: mongodb log file print helped. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `console` object defined in the MongoDB shell.

You'll need to use the `print` and `printjson` functions that are globally available.

```
print("Hi! I'm in your log!");
```

Anything printed will be emitted to the current log file. If there is no log file defined in your mongo configuration, then it will be emitted to the screen/stdout, which would allow you to pipe the results to a file if you wanted (or you might just want to use the log file generated by MongoDB).

If you had a bunch of code you were using that had `console.log`, you could build a polyfill that redirected the output via a `print` and `printjson`.